# Setting up a Next.js application on DirectAdmin

Tags: node.js, nginx, next.js, directadmin, nginx-unit

I developed an application using Next.js and deployed it on my own hosting, which utilizes the DirectAdmin panel. I run my application through NGINX Unit as described in this link: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server.
However, it's giving me a 503 error. I would appreciate your guidance to resolve the issue.

i try run my application